# Sparql Query Optimization for possible predicates between entity types

Tags: query-optimization, sparql

I am trying to formulate a sparql query such that I get all the possible predicates between two entity types. Here is my approach:

```
SELECT distinct ?p 
WHERE 
{ ?url1 rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Town> . 
?url2 rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/District> . 
?url1 ?p ?url2 .}
```

However, this approach is not efficient, is there any way to optimize this query?

Comment: Your query currently gets all predicates by which instances of Town are connected to instances of District. Is this what you want?

Comment: @evsheino yes, all predicates connecting two types.

Comment: Ok, but your query only gets predicates from town instance to district instance (and not vice versa). Is this the intention?

Comment: @evsheino no, I am looking for predicate from both ways. This query is all I could come up with.

Comment: You have to use SPARQL `UNION` to get it for both directions. And there is no more efficient way since this is a very basic query.

Comment: By the way, your returns no results on DBpedia

Comment: @Anish after trying your query in DBpedia it seems pretty fast to me. Did not return any results for Town and District, but does for e.g. Town and AdministrativeRegion. The query takes about a second, and with a `UNION` in order to get the predicates both ways it takes about three seconds.

Comment: @evsheino I am trying to run about 100 queries by changing the types. This is getting me time out error(